# Quering a webpage and find an excel file available for download in that

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I have created a web page.So now i want to display some data in a tab in my website by querying a website in which we have to give the drop down value ( assigning this drop-down is important )  and find an excel file available for download in that and displaying the data i want from that excel sheet in my website dynamically .

Comment: Could you clean up your question and give some code samples?

Comment: HI Severin.Thanks for your comment.Actually i want to know if i can read an excel file which is located in another website as a download link(Excel file). I just want to display some data from excel file in tabs in my website.But i dont know how can i connect to that excel file and extract data.

Sorry if the question is too confusing.I will try to explain it clearly if you still didnt got my objective.